# Stop a value from being incremented in each dictionary iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary

I'm using Python 2.7. I have two tsv data files that I read into two dictionaries that I would like to calculate the `recall` score of them, so I need to calculate the `tp` and `fn`. 
These how my dictionaries look:

```
gold = {'A11':'cat', 'A22':'cat', 'B3':'mouse'}
results = {'A2':'cat', 'B2':'dog'}
```

My code mainly iterates the `gold` dictionary and removes the digits at the end of the `gold` dictionary `key` as well as `results` `key`. Then, checks if the keys match in order to find if their values match to calculate the `tp`. However, my code seems to always increment the `fn`. Here is my runable code:

```
from __future__ import division
import string


def eval():
        tp=0 #true positives
        fn=0 #false negatives
        fp=0#false positives

        gold = {'A11':'cat', 'A22':'cat', 'B3':'mouse'}
        results = {'A2':'cat', 'B2':'dog'}

       #iterate gold dictionary
        for i,j in gold.items():

            #remove the digits off gold keys
            i_stripped = i.rstrip(string.digits)

            #iterate results dictionary
            for k,v in results.items():

                #remove the digits off results keys
                k_stripped = k.rstrip(string.digits)

                # check if key match!
                if i_stripped == k_stripped:

                  #check if values match then increment tp
                  if j == v:
                      tp += 1

                      #delete dictionary entries to avoid counting them again
                      del gold_copy[i]
                      del results_copy[k]

                      #get out of this loop we found a match! 
                      break
                continue

            # NO match was found in the results, then consider it as fn 
            fn += 1 #<------ wrong calculations caused in this line

        print 'tp = %.2f   fn =  %.2f    recall = %.2f ' % (tp, fn, float(tp)/(tp+fn))
```

and this is the output:

```
tp = 1.00   fn =  3.00    recall = 0.25
```

`fn` is incorrect, it should be `2` instead of `3`. How can I stop `fn` from being incremented in each iteration? Any guidance will be truly appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: It might help if you change "contiue" to "continue"?

Comment: @bobbel lol that was just a typo when copying the code from the ide. However, still fn is incremented in each iteration

Comment: Most likely you need to put the line that controls the fn increase  under one of the if conditions

Comment: @Repiklis so could you please indicate how to check if the last iteration on the results dictionary has occurred and now it's time to increment the fn? I tried sorted(results_copy.keys())[-1] but resulted in fn = 0. Thanks

Comment: Others can much more easily help you if you have documentation in your code and use descriptive variable names.

Comment: @jpobst I'll try to edit accordingly. thanks

Comment: @jpobst thank you for the advice! now the questions is readable and neater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you only want to increment `fn` only if no match was found in the results. You can use a variable to track whether or not the match has been found, and based on that you increment `fn`. Here below I adapted your code and used `match_found` for that purpose.

```
#iterate gold dictionary
 for i,j in gold.items():

     # create a variable that indicates whether a match was found
     match_found = False

     #remove the digits off gold keys
     i_stripped = i.rstrip(string.digits)

     #iterate results dictionary
     for k,v in results.items():

         #remove the digits off results keys
         k_stripped = k.rstrip(string.digits)

         # check if key match!
         if i_stripped == k_stripped:

           #check if values match then increment tp
           if j == v:
               tp += 1

               # now a match has been found, change variable
               match_found = True

               #delete dictionary entries to avoid counting them again
               del gold_copy[i]
               del results_copy[k]

               #get out of this loop we found a match! 
               break
         continue

     # NO match was found in the results, then consider it as fn 
     # now, only if no match has been found, increment fn
     if not match_found :
         fn += 1 #<------ wrong calculations caused in this line
```

Comment: YESSS I was about to answer my own question, I had the same exact variable added and now it works perfectly!! thanks wow that was so simple what was i thinking ;d thanks again

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't exactly what you need, you should be able to modify it to make it work.

```
tp = 0 #true positives
fn = 0 #false negatives
fp = 0 #false positives


gold = {'A11':'cat', 'A22':'cat', 'B3':'mouse'}
results = {'A2':'cat', 'B2':'dog'}

for gold_k, gold_v in gold.items():
    # Remove digits and make lower case
    clean_gold_k = gold_k.rstrip(string.digits).lower()

    for results_k, results_v in results.items():
        # Remove digits and make lower case
        clean_results_k = results_k.rstrip(string.digits).lower()

        keys_agree = clean_gold_k == clean_results_k
        values_agree = gold_v.lower() == results_v.lower()

        print('\n-------------------------------------')
        print('Gold = ' + gold_k + ': ' + gold_v)
        print('Result = ' + results_k + ': ' + results_v)

        if keys_agree and values_agree:
            print('tp')
            tp += 1

        elif keys_agree and not values_agree:
            print('fn')
            fn += 1

        elif values_agree and not keys_agree:
            print('fp')
            fp += 1
```

Comment: thanks. but it counts 2 tp! there is only one tp. so maybe you should delete the counted records as shown in the question. Also fn should be 2 not 1. thanks

Comment: I want the fn to be incremented only after iterating through the entire results dictionary and finding any tp. thanks